# Updating content to the database onclick event

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I spent the last 2 days trying to make the following code work.
I have three forms with content in different languages. For each of them there is an Edit button which popup a text editor. What I would like to do is when I click the button "Save and close" the edited content would be updated in the database using javascript (AJAX) and PHP/SQL but in the console it gives me the following error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: valueContent is not defined**. So here is the code I have so far.

```
$mvccont .=
    "<form action='edit_language/".ID.".raw' method='post' target='pop' class='comparelist' style='clear: both' onsubmit='window.open(\"\", \"pop\", \"width=0,height=0,resizeable,scrollbars\");'>".
        "<input type='hidden' name='keyword' value='".$keyword."'>".
        "<table style='width:100%; border-collapse: collapse;' >".
        "<tr><td width='20%' ><div class='info' style='width:100%; border:none;' >".
            substr($keyword, 0, 20)."<a title='".$keyword."'><input type='submit' value='Save' class='BUYN'/></a>".
            "<a href='edit_language/".$keyword."/delete'><input type='button' value='Delete' class='NONA'/></a>".
        "</div></td>";

        foreach($lan as $lang=>$lame) {
            $idk = str_replace(" ", "", $keyword).$lang;
            $mvccont .=
            "<td><div class='number3'".(($red[$keyword][$lang]=='')?" style='background: #fcc;'":"")." style='border:none;' >".
                "<input type='hidden' name='touch".$lang.$keyword."'/>".
                "<input type='text' id='s".$idk."' name='a".$lang."' value='".htmlentities($lame, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")."' onchange=\"this.style.borderColor='#ff0000'; document.getElementsByName('touch".$lang.$keyword."')[0].value='true'\"/><a onclick='popbox(false, ".$idk.", true); mce();'><input type='button' value='Edit' class='BUYN'/></a>".
                "<br />".($red[$keyword][$lang]).
                "<script>".
                    "function falaffel".$idk."(step) {".
                        "var l".$idk."=document.getElementById('s".$idk."').value;".
                        "if(step==1) {".
                            "return '<textarea>'+l".$idk."+'</textarea><input type=\"button\" value=\"Save & close\" class=\"NONA\" onclick=\"'+\"document.getElementById('s".$idk."').value=tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); ".$idk."=falaffel".$idk."(1); popboxremove(); document.getElementById('s".$idk."').style.borderColor='#ff0000'; updateValue(); document.getElementsByName('touch".$lang.$keyword."')[0].value='true' \"+'\">';".
                        "}".
                        "return l".$idk.";".
                    "}".
                    "var ".$idk." = falaffel".$idk."(1); ".
                "</script>".
            "</div></td>";
        }
        $mvccont .=
    "</tr></table></form>";
```

Then here is the AJAX code:

```
function updateValue(){
var ajaxRequest = getXmlHttpRequestObject();

ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var valueContent = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "comp/update_lang.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(valueContent);
}
```

And finally the PHP code:

```
<?php
foreach(array(1=>"en", 2=>"it", 3=>"pl") as $id=>$lang) {
    if($_POST["touch".$id.$_POST["keyword"]]=="true") {
        $sql = "UPDATE translat SET value='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["a".$id])."', date=".NOWTIME." WHERE lang=".$id." AND keyword='".urldecode($_POST["keyword"])."'";
        $insert = $db->query($sql);
        $insert->execute();
        @unlink(TEMP."lang_".$lang.".cache");
    }
}
$mvccont .=
"<script>".
    "window.close();".
"</script>";
die($mvccont);
?>
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Where exactly is your error coming from?  Executing the php or the javascript?  If it's javascript and you're using a very old browser, perhaps the window doesn't have an XMLHttpRequest, so you may want to add an else statement to catch that situation.

Comment: if you have not much expirence with js it better to you just use jquery

Comment: Hello DJStroky, I have done some changes on my AJAX code and now the error message has changed (I have updated this post). I think the problem is that I need to pass PHP value into the AJAX code to send them to the PHP code which will update the database. But how can I pass dynamic PHP values to AJAX? Thank you